# Do Nick and Juliette have a television?

Tags: grimm, props

I've been going through episodes of Grimm trying to figure out if they have one and I can't find one. I know that Juliette has a Mac and that Nick has a laptop so I am wondering if they only watch media on their computers?

Granted, we don't get to see them with much downtime in the show, but I would assume that they have some. There also does not appear to be a media collection, although that may either be in the furniture or completely digital. Also, it's one thing to not have television service and another to not watch movies or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after further review of the episodes, they do in fact have a television as seen in the beginning of episode 11 of season one.